# Will CruiseControl.NET queue triggered builds while a forced build is already running?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

What happens to a CruiseControl.NET project if a trigger fires to build the project while it's already building due to someone "Force" building it earlier?

Will the build request of the trigger got queued?

We use CCNET 1.5 and 1.6.

Comment: Have you tried this scenario? If so, what behavior do you observe?

Comment: I just want to whether it will show an option to trigger the build while its already running? I think it will show the status as Running..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nothing, while a build is running triggers are not executed. However if you configured a `sourcecontrol` block for example for svn or p4, modifications during forced build will still be detected and cause another build in consequence.

You can see easier this if you add `<queueStatusServerPlugin />` to the `serverPlugins` in `dashboard.config`.